# How to Add Different Custom Boost Factor Query Scores in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm Using 3 Custom Boost Factor Queries. And I want to Find The Sum Of All Those Scores and Sorted in Desc Orders...

I'm Trail Include Something Like This... How to find Sum of These Three Boost Factor Queries?

```
QueryBuilders.customBoostFactorQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()) // Your query
                .boostFactor(5);

QueryBuilders.customBoostFactorQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()) // Your query
                .boostFactor(3);

QueryBuilders.customBoostFactorQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()) // Your query
                .boostFactor(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at function_score:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html